# Proper procedure for installing into /usr/local?

Tags: linux

Yesterday I downloaded an app called mvPod, which came in a [tarball](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mvpod/files/mvpod/0.1%20alpha2/mvPod-0.0.1.67.tar.gz/download).

I was under the impression that if I have any programs not installed by the package manager, they belong in `/usr/local` rather than `/usr`. But if I put the executable in `/usr/local/bin`, and the jar files into `/usr/local/lib`, I get runtime errors about being unable to load the Java classes. So I resorted to putting things in `/usr/bin` and `/usr/lib` and it worked fine.

Is this something that can only be corrected by compiling differently, or am I missing an installation step?

I'm running Ubuntu Karmic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with putting hand installs into `/usr` rather than `/usr/local` is that

- you won't know immediately how something was installed which makes fixing problems harder later on
- some package could clobber *part* of your installation or vice versa (just part is *much* worse than all, trust me)

The reason a `/usr/local` installation wasn't working is almost certainly associated with some search path or another. These can be configured for each program doing the searching or stored in environment variables, or often make use of both methods. For all types of programs, you'll want to be sure that the `PATH`, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`, and `MAN_PATH` environment variables are updated. Java may involve a `CLASS_PATH` or something similar. Maybe you'll get a more specific answer here, or as a last resort there is always the documentation.

---

Another thing: some unixs expect local installs in `/opt` rather than `/usr/local`. It is always worth checking the local convention on that.

Comment: +1 for environment setup. everything will just work if he sets his paths properly.

Comment: Thanks for the info! This sort of thing was my first thought (before posting this question) but I was a bit turned off that googling "LD_LIBRARY_PATH" mostly finds people saying that it's a hack. It seems it would be more correct to fix this at make time, but it's annoying then that the distributed binaries were made with the "wrong" paths...

Comment: @Owen: the dynamic loader (`ldd`) has a config file (`ld.so.conf` usually in the `/etc` hierarchy, and managed with `ldconfig`) to tell it where to look on a global basis: If you have root access you can fix *that* instead of fooling around with your personal PATHs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`--prefix` option](http://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Directory-Variables.html#Directory-Variables) with configure, make or both.

> ./configure --prefix=/usr

or

> make prefix=/usr install

This will install in `/usr` instead of the default `/usr/local`.